# MySql search using LIKE clause not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-like

I am trying to implement a search using php5 pdo and mysql. What I am trying to do is search for a given set of keywords in my table 'posts' and return records that contain any of the given keywords in the column 'title'. But it returns no result set even if I give keywords that I know exist in the table. I use collation 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'. Here is my code:

```
 <?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$charset="utf8mb4";
$dsn="mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt=[  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];
$pdo=new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass,$opt);
$keywords=$_POST['keywords'];
$keywordArray=explode(' ',$keywords);
$n=count($keywordArray);
$query="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE ?";
$keywordArray[0]="'%".$keywordArray[0]."%'";
for($i=1;$i<$n;$i++){
  $keywordArray[$i]="'%".$keywordArray[$i]."%'";
  $query=$query." OR title LIKE ?";
}
$query=$query." LIMIT 50;";
     echo $query;
$stmt=$pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($keywordArray);
$res=$stmt->fetchAll();
echo "<br><h1>SEARCH RESULTS:</h1><br><ul>";
if($res){
foreach($res as $row){
  echo "<li>".$row['date']."<a href=\"viewpost.php?postid=".$row['id']."\">".$row['title']."</a></li><br>";
}
}
else{
echo "<h2 style=\"color:red;\">No results!</h2>";
}
echo "</ul></div>";
}
?>
```

Its working inside the console.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%hit%' OR title LIKE '%fifa%';
```

returns two rows. But searching with 'hit fifa' using the form returns zero rows.

Comment: The ?  for the LIKE-pattern is invalid... use a proper formatted LIKE-pattern.

Comment: Can you please point out the mistake in my pattern? Sorry but I've already googled it several times but I couldnt  find a solution.

Comment: @Werner I think you're confusing the ? which is the placeholder for a parameter, with it being actually part of the LIKE expression.

Comment: I do know ? is a placeholder. I am trying to replace the ? s with '%each_keyword%'.

Comment: @abhiramsanthosh my comment was directed at Werner, not you. I think you know what you are doing with the ?. I have written an answer below regarding your actual issue.

Comment: @ADyson It's PDO, overlooked that. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Werner No problem. Just a small point though - PDO can be used with or without parameterised queries. And mysqli accepts ? as a placeholder too. It's not the use of PDO in general which is the thing you missed...it's the use of _parameterised queries_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using prepared statements, you don't need the single quotes around your expression. Change your code, removing those quotes, to

```
$query="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE ?";
$keywordArray[0]="%".$keywordArray[0]."%";
for($i=1;$i<$n;$i++){
  $keywordArray[$i]="%".$keywordArray[$i]."%";
  $query.=" OR title LIKE ?";
}
```

It was treating the quote marks as being part of the value inside the parameter. So you would have ended up with SQL something like

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '\'%Something%\''
```

and clearly this won't match, because the values in the database won't have single quotes at the start and end in most cases.

With the changes, it should translate into SQL like this

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%Something%'
```

This is because the parameterisation process handles the quoting and escaping job automatically for you - it's one way in which it protects against SQL injection attacks ( and also, incidentally, against syntax errors caused by erroneous / unescaped quote marks).

---

P.S. If a request is ever submitted to this code where no keyword at all was provided, then the code will crash because it assumes there is always a value in `$keywordArray[0]`. Consider revising this to either validate that a keyword was provided, or just loop the whole array and, if no keywords are submitted, simply don't add a WHERE clause to the query at all.

Comment: It worked and thanks for the detailed answer. About the no keyword case, I've written 'required' inside the html input tag, will that help?

Comment: it will as long as no-one messes with the client-side code (easy, if you know how), or decides to use some other tool such as PostMan to send HTTP requests to your server directly. Client-side validation is nice for user experience, but you cannot rely on it to always check your input. Server-side checks must always be made as well (in fact, they should be the first checks you write, then you can add the client-side stuff later if you have time).

Comment: Shame on me I didnt notice that, because even I play with post variables and requests with burpsuit. Will do that.